# Use dplyr's mutate with columns that may or may not exist

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `df` and use the `mutate` function to add a `total = a + b + c + d` column.

By default, `mutate` seems to only work with columns that already exist, but my `df` comes different each time.

This time, column `c` is missing (next time, maybe `a` is missing, etc.)

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
                 b = c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25),
                 d = c(31, 32, 33, 34, 35))

   a  b  d
1 11 21 31
2 12 22 32
3 13 23 33
4 14 24 34
5 15 25 35
```

If I try using `mutate`, I get the following error:

```
df <- dplyr::mutate(df,
                    total = a + b + c + d)
```

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `total`.
i `total = a + b + c + d`.
x object 'c' not found
```

Is there a way to make `mutate` work without having to check if all the columns exist beforehand?

Comment: Do the names of your columns follow a specific pattern?

Comment: du you always want to add up all columns?

Comment: Yes, I always sum these columns only.

The columns are a, b, c, d (for simplicity's sake). But sometimes, only 'a' exists, then 'a' and 'b' etc. but not all four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(across(matches("^\\w$"))))
```

This sums up every row that is named with a single letter.

If you want to sum up every row, replace `matches("^\\w$")` by `everything()`.

Comment: This answer is closest (and simplest) to what I needed. 

I simply pasted the column names using OR operator and Regex.

mutate(total = rowSums(across(matches("Random_col1|Other_col2|Extra_col3"))))

Comment: In this case see Park's answer. I think this suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Using `any_of`

```
check_list <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
df %>% 
  select(any_of(check_list)) %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(.))

   a  b  d total
1 11 21 31    63
2 12 22 32    66
3 13 23 33    69
4 14 24 34    72
5 15 25 35    75
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `rowSums`,

```
df = df %>% mutate(sum= rowSums(df))
   a  b  d sum
1 11 21 31 63
2 12 22 32 66
3 13 23 33 69
4 14 24 34 72
5 15 25 35 75
```

Answer (score 1):

Might work for you?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(select(., a:d))) 
#    a  b  d sum
# 1 11 21 31  63
# 2 12 22 32  66
# 3 13 23 33  69
# 4 14 24 34  72
# 5 15 25 35  75
```